# How low quality does an answer have to be to be recognized as low quality

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Few days ago I flagged an [answer as low quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-a-nsdate/33922065#33922065), that answered the question how to dadd several date to a NSDate object in swift by saying you should create an extension, but leaves the task of explaining this to a link, that is dead ever since. Also it does also not mention that for the shown line of code operator overloading is needed as-well.

My flag was declined

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

This answer makes only sense, if I would be able to open the link and I think it is common sense that link only answers are considered low quality or now answer at all, regardless if they work or not. Essential parts should be included.

Am I mistaken? How do I recognize, low quality, if this isn't low quality?

Comment: Of interest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189362/why-were-these-very-low-quality-flags-declined/189373#189373

Comment: Rule of thumb is to only flag stuff that does not deserve to be on the site (it should be deleted) as VLQ.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, so you say it is too low for the site if it is too low? I smell an infinite recursion.

Comment: Is the text "_This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed._" not helpful enough?  As for that specific answer, it appears to be a (possibly unhelpful) answer.

Comment: How could it be an answer if it uses not out of the box available methods and operators but does not explain how to add these?

Comment: @vikingosegundo its a poor answer you downvote?

Comment: IME, finding/recognizing low-quality questions/answers is not difficult:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that answer can be safely removed. It requires the content of the link to work, and with the linked site down indefinitely it's rendered useless. I deleted it.

I can't speak for the moderator involved, but someone not familiar with the language might see the code in the answer and assume that without the link it was still a viable answer. They wouldn't realize that `.days` isn't a standard method and requires the code at the link to work. Without that link being operational, the code does nothing.

In a case like this, I might recommend spelling that out in a custom flag. Something like

> The code in this answer depends entirely on an external link, which is now dead. This answer can be safely removed.

We almost always accept flags like this and are able to act on the answers.

Comment: Great recommendation, I will do it like suggested in the future.